# Closed form for sequence: $\sum_{j=1}^k 2^j j^{1/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Any idea how to find the closed form for either of following sequences: 
$$
A(k) = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^j j^{1/2}
$$
or 
$$
B(k) = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^a, \quad \quad a:= {j^{1/2}}
$$
Note: closed form for one of these sequences can result in closed form of the other.

Comment: wolfram alpha gives a cryptic answer, maybe it will be helpful to you but I certainly got nothing from it:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+n+of+2%5Ejsqrt%28j%29

Comment: For $A(k)$ the result is not so cryptic but involves special functions that you probably do not know yet (don't worry : you will learn about them).